# Uncaught TypeError: this.perform is not a function in rails 6

Tags: actioncable, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm starting whith ActionCable in rails 6 and it works very well but 
I don't know why the ".perform" method is undefined in poke_channel.js.
Please I need your help

```
# in app/channels/poke_channel.rb

class PokeChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "poke"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def poke(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('poke')
  end
end

# in app/javascript/channels/poke_channels.js
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("PokeChannel", {
  connected() { 
    $('#poke-btn').click(function(event) {
      this.perform("poke", {});
    });
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    alert('Poked');
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  },

});

# in app/views/messages/index.html.erb

<button id="poke-btn">Poke</button>
```

and when I click on the button,

```
poke_channel.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: this.perform is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (poke_channel.js:6)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (event.js:328)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (event.js:148)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the following worked for me.

Try taking your subscription that is created and save it to something and then call perform on that.

```js
this.channel = consumer.subscriptions.create("PokeChannel", {
  connected() { 
    $('#poke-btn').click(function(event) {
      this.channel.perform("poke", {});
    });
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },
  ...
});
```